# Issues Creating Environments For AWS Lambda Service In CodeStar And CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I used AWS CodeStar to create a new application with the "Express.js Aws Lambda Webservice" CodeStar template. This was great because it set me up with a simple CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline. By default the pipeline has 3 steps for grabbing the source code from a git repo, running the build step, and then deploying to "dev" environment.

**My issue is that I can't set it up so that my pipeline has multiple environments: dev, staging, and prod.**

My current deploy step has 2 actions: *GenerateChangeSet* and *ExecuteChangeSet*. Here are the configurations for the actions in original dev environment build step which work great:

[image]

[image]

I've created a new deploy stage at the end of my pipeline to deploy to staging, but honestly I'm not sure how to change the configurations. I'm thinking ultimately I want to be able to go into the AWS Lambda section of the AWS console and see three independent lambda functions: binance-bot-dev, binance-bot-staging, binance-bot-prod. Then each of these I could set as cloudwatch scheduled events or expose with their own api gateway url.

This is the configuration that I tried to use for a new deployment stage:

[image]

[image]

I'm really not sure if this configuration is correct and what exactly I should change in order to deploy in the way I want.

For example, should I be changing "Stack name", or should I keep that as "awscodestar-binance-bot-lambda" or change it for each environment as I am here?

Also, I'm pointing to a different template.yml file in the project. The original template.yml looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
- AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

Resources:
  Dev:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: dev
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
```

For template.staging.yml I use the exact same config except I changed "Dev:" to "Staging:" under "Resources", and I also changed the value of the NODE_ENV environment variable. So, I'm basically wondering **is this the correct configuration for what I'm trying to achieve?**

Assuming that everything in the configuration is correct, I then need to troubleshoot this error. With everything set as described above I can run my pipeline, but when it gets to my staging build step the *GenerateChage_Staging* action fails with this error message:

> Action execution failed User:
>   arn:aws:sts::954459734159:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-binance-bot-CodePipeline/1524253307698
>   is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on
>   resource:
>   arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:954459734159:stack/awscodestar-binance-bot-lambda-staging/*
>   (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   AccessDenied; Request ID: dd801664-44d2-11e8-a2de-8fa6c42cbf86)

It seem to me from this error message that I need to add the "cloudformation:DescribeStacks" for  my "CodeStarWorker-binance-bot-CodePipeline" so I go to IAM -> Roles and click on the CodeStarWorker-binance-bot-CodePipeline role. However, when I click on "CodeStarWorker-binance-bot-CodePipeline" and drill into the policy information for *CloudFormation* it looks like this role already has permissions for "DescribeStacks"!

[image]

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong or offer any guidance on understanding and thinking about how to do multiple environments with AWS CodePipeline that would be great. thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I changed the "Stack name" in my Deploy_To_Staging pipeline stage back to "awscodestar-binance-bot-lambda". However, I then get this error form the GenerateChange_Staging action:

> Action execution failed Invalid TemplatePath:
>   binance-bot-BuildArtifact::template-export.staging.yml. Artifact
>   binance-bot-BuildArtifact doesn't exist

**UPDATE 2:**
In the root of my project I have the buildspec.yml file that was generated by CodeStar. It looks like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # Install dependencies needed for running tests
      - npm install

      # Upgrade AWS CLI to the latest version
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # Discover and run unit tests in the 'tests' directory
      - npm test
  build:
    commands:
      # Use AWS SAM to package the application using AWS CloudFormation
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.yml
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.staging.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.staging.yml
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.prod.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.prod.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template-export.yml
```

I then added this to the CloudFormation section:

Then I add this to the "build: -> commands:" section:

```
  - aws cloudformation package --template template.staging.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.staging.yml
  - aws cloudformation package --template template.prod.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.prod.yml
```

And I added this to the "files:"

- template-export.staging.yml
- template-export.prod.yml

HOWEVER, I am **still** getting an error that "binance-bot-BuildArtifact does not exist".

Here is the full error after making the buildspec.yml change:

> Action execution failed Invalid TemplatePath:
>   binance-bot-BuildArtifact::template-export.staging.yml. Artifact
>   binance-bot-BuildArtifact doesn't exist

It seems very strange to me that I can access "binance-bot-BuildArtifact" in one stage of the pipeline but not another. Could it be that the build artifact is only available to the one pipeline stage directly after the build stage? Can someone please help me to be able to access this "binance-bot-BuildArtifact"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> For example, should I be changing "Stack name", or should I keep that as "awscodestar-binance-bot-lambda" or change it for each environment as I am here?

You should use a unique stack name for each environment. If you didn't, you would be replacing your 'dev' environment with your 'staging' environment, and so forth.

> So, I'm basically wondering is this the correct configuration for what I'm trying to achieve?

I don't think so. You should use the exact same template for each environment. In order to change the environment name for each of your deploys, you can use the 'Parameter Overrides' field to choose the correct value for your 'Environment' parameter.

> it looks like this role already has permissions for "DescribeStacks"!

Could the issue here be that your IAM role only has DescribeStacks permission for the dev stack? It looks like it does not have permission to describe the staging stack. Maybe you can add a 'wildcard'/asterisk to the policy so that it matches all of your stack names?

> Could it be that the build artifact is only available to the one pipeline stage directly after the build stage?

No, that has not been my experience with CodePipeline. Unfortunately I don't know why it's telling you that your artifact can't be found.

Comment: thanks! But what do you mean by 'Parameter Overrides field"? Where is that?

Comment: I see know that he meant the "Parameter Overrides" field in the settings in AWS CodePipeline for a "Deploy" action that uses CloudFormation, under the "Advanced" expandable section.

Answer (score 0):

robrtsql has already provided some good advice in terms of using the same template in both stages.

You might find [this walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html) useful. 
Basically, it describes adding a Cloudformation "[template configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-cfn-artifacts.html#w2ab2c13c15c15)" which allows you to specify parameters to the Cloudformation stack.

This will allow you to deploy the same template in both your dev and prod environments, but also allow you to tell the difference between a dev deployment and a prod deployment, by choosing a different template configuration in each stage.